# issue converting SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, linq

The following query I wrote in SQL Management Studio and it works fine

```
select distinct location.LocationId, location.Name, location.WorkArea,
            crop.CropId, HubCropTypes.Name, crop.recommendedDate, activity.ApplicationDate, activity.Type, crop.IsDeleted cropDeleted, activity.IsDeleted activityDeleted
from location 
    left outer join crop on location.LocationId = crop.LocationId
    left outer join activity on crop.CropId = Activity.CropID
    left outer join HubCropTypes on crop.HubCropTypeID = HubCropTypes.HubCropTypeID
where location.FarmId = 'xxxxxxxxx'
and location.IsDeleted = 0
order by location.LocationId,crop.recommendedDate, location.Name
```

However, the LINQ version does not, and after playing around in SQL I found it's down to the left joins.  I thought DefaultIfEmpty replaces left join in LINQ?

```
 var query = (from l in _db.Locations
                             join c in _db.Crops.DefaultIfEmpty() on l.LocationId equals c.LocationId
                             join a in _db.Activities.DefaultIfEmpty() on c.CropId equals a.CropID
                             join h in _db.HubCropTypes.DefaultIfEmpty() on c.HubCropTypeID equals h.HubCropTypeID
                             where l.FarmId == FarmID
                             where l.IsDeleted == false
                             select new
                             {
                                 LocationID = l.LocationId,
                                 LocationName = l.Name,
                                 WorkArea = l.WorkArea,
                                 CropID = c.CropId,
                                 CropName = h.Name,
                                 CropRecommendedDate = c.RecommendedDate,
                                 ActivityApplicationDate = a.ApplicationDate,
                                 ActivityType = a.Type,
                                 isCropDeleted = c.IsDeleted,
                                 isActivityDeleted = a.IsDeleted
                             }).Distinct();
```

Comment: why are you doing a big messy join, why are you just loading the data you need filtered includes, and then construct the dto server side

Comment: You may need a left outer join.  See msnd : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: you arent doing the joins correctly

Comment: _db.Locations.Include(x => x.Crops.SelectMany(c => c.Activities)) etc...